# Slick 3: insertOrUpdate not working

Tags: postgresql, slick, upsert

I'm using slick with Postgresql 9.6.1, Plya! 2.5 and play-slick 2.0.2.

(I also use slick-pg 0.14.3 but I don't think that it changes anything here.)

I'm using `insertOrUpdate` in a very straight forward way but I still get a unique exception.

I have a very simple test using `insertOrUpdate`: 
if I run it several times I always get an sql exception:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ga_client_id_pkey"
  Detail: Key (client_id)=(1885746393.1464005051) already exists
```

However, my table is defined with `client_id` as primary key:

```
def clientId = column[String]("client_id", O.PrimaryKey)
```

and defined in sql as followed:

```
client_id    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY
```

The function tested simply does:

```
db.run(gaClientIds.insertOrUpdate(gaClientId))
```

and the controller simply calls this methods and does nothing else.

A strange thing is that launching the methods itself several times don't lead to the error but the controller does although it only calls the method.

Is `insertOrUpdate` slick function not sure yet or am I missing something?

Comment: Same problem on my side with slick3.2.1. @Simon did you find a solution?

Comment: No unfortunately the only solution I have found is to write the database call in plain sql...

Comment: This was my solution as well

Comment: In my case, sometimes it gets saved, sometimes it fails. I am unable to reproduce it locally, though using same library and versions on upper environments, its breaking even in production sometimes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

insertOrUpdate is only supported in MySQL driver

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/supported-databases.html

You can try this library which gives you the implementation of insertOrUpdate/upsert

https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg

This is how we use it on current project.

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import slick.basic.Capability

object DBComponent {

  private val config = ConfigFactory.load()

  val driver = config.getString("rdbms.properties.driver") match {
    case "org.h2.Driver" => slick.jdbc.H2Profile
    case _               => MyPostgresProfile
  }

  import driver.api._

  val db: Database = Database.forConfig("rdbms.properties")

}

trait MyPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile {

  // Add back `capabilities.insertOrUpdate` to enable native `upsert` support; for postgres 9.5+
  override protected def computeCapabilities: Set[Capability] =
    super.computeCapabilities + slick.jdbc.JdbcCapabilities.insertOrUpdate

  override val api: MyAPI.type = MyAPI

  object MyAPI extends API
}

object MyPostgresProfile extends MyPostgresProfile
```

Comment: IMO, the doc lets think that it is supported for every driver and I had never seen this page before. Thanks for your response.